# ImageTile in ListPicker not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, listpicker

I'm trying to display a Tile in a ListPicker. This means when the user clicks on the ListPicker, a Tile like this should pop up:

http://igrali.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/notestiles_thumb.png

source: http://igrali.com/2011/09/01/how-to-use-the-coding4fun-tile-control/

My problem is that I want to have 2 columns just like in the picture, but my images are always showing under each other and not 2 images next to each other. So it looks currently like this:

http://www.imgbox.de/users/public/images/ONVAEOO7Av.png

This is my xaml code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <model:Bundesland x:Key="Bundesland"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullItemTemplateBundesland">
            <coding4fun:Tile Background="Transparent" >
            <coding4fun:Tile.Content>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Flagge, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="200" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Land}" FontSize="25"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </coding4fun:Tile.Content>
        </coding4fun:Tile>
                <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Land}" FontSize="25"/>-->
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<tool:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding BundeslandListe, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Bundesland, Mode=TwoWay}" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullItemTemplateBundesland}"/>
```

My class *Bundesland* contains the image and the text shown below the image

```
public class Bundesland
{
    public ImageSource Flagge { get; set; }
    public string Land { get; set; }

    public Bundesland()
    {
    }

    public Bundesland(ImageSource flagge, string land)
    {
        Flagge = flagge;
        Land = land;
    }
}
```

I've also tried to use ImageTile and MetroFlow, but it still won't work. Is it because I can display the items ina Listpicker only under each other and not next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

In the blog you refer, the author override default `ListBox's ItemPanelTemplate` to achieve that 2 columns look, using `WrapPanel` in WP toolkit :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Notes}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <toolkit:WrapPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Try to do the same by overriding default `ListPicker's ItemPanelTemplate` to use `WrapPanel` control. For example :

```
<toolkit:ListPicker>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemsPanel>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```